# Correct interpretation of /. (ReplaceAll)

Tags: replacement

Consider that you have a complicated expression, which is expensive in terms of running time and memory, and depends on some (initial) parameters. You want to test it for some simple values of the parameters, which simplifies a lot the evaluation.

For the sake of comprehension, suppose that the expression is

```
Table[k^2, {k, n}]
```

which depends on the parameter `n`.

If you test the expression with

```
Table[k^2,{k,n}] /. {n -> 5}
```

you obtain

```
Table::iterb: Iterator {k,n} does not have appropriate bounds. >>
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
```

so it seems to me that MMA in some sense pre-evaluate `Table[k^2, {k, n}]` , then substitute `n` with `5` and then evaluate `Table[k^2, {k, 5}]`. 
This is in partial contradiction with my understanding of the rule `/.`. I always though that MMA would evaluate `Table[k^2, {k, n}]` given that (or equivalently, assuming that) `n` is equal to `5` (and without making the "global" assignment `n=5`). That is, I though MMA implicitly does something like

```
f[n_]:=Table[k^2, {k, n}];
f[5]
```

but in this case, there are no errors.

So, what does MMA do? What is the correct intepretation of /.?

Note that in my original expression, I got only the error (I exceeded the recursion limit), and not the evaluation with the substitution.

Comment: [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) does not have the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) (or `HoldFirst`), so both arguments will be evaluated **before** the replacement is done.

Comment: `Trace[Table[k^2, {k, n}] /. {n -> 5}]` confirms what @MichaelE2 and @Nicola say.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a quick way to evaluate `Table[k^2, {k, n}]` with `n` equal to 5 without making the assignment `n=5` or writing explicitly `Table[k^2, {k, 5}]`? Imagine the parameter `n` is repeated several times in the expression so that I don't want to change them all, and that I do not want to define a dummy function `f[n_]` .

Comment: `Block[{n = 5}, Table[..]]`.  Or `Hold[Table[..]] /. n->5 // ReleaseHold`; or a similar thing with `Inactivate` and `Active` (V10+ only). Possibly `Quiet@Table[..] /. {n -> 5}`, although it will be evaluated.

Comment: `With` is the function normally used to inject values into held expressions: `With[{n = 5}, Table[k^2, {k, n}]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReplaceAll` follows [The Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html). Some function have [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Attributes.html) that make them follow a [Non-Standard Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) procedure.